# if data exists statement in JSON not working

Tags: jquery, json, api, if-statement, debugging

I have a JSON snippet that should detect the existence of a particular type of data in an API.
The api endpoint is https://fortnite-api.com/v1/stats/br/v2?name=chefbezos
when I run a console.log(data.data.stats.all.trio), it gives me null. But it still shows the div with the class of trioStats. Is there something wrong with the code since `data.data.stats.all.trio == "null"` is true since the `console.log(data.data.stats.all.trio)` is null. Thanks for any help!

```
if(typeof data.data.stats.all.trio == "null") {
var trioAllMP = data.data.stats.all.trio.minutesPlayed;
var trioAllMatches = data.data.stats.all.trio.matches;
var trioML = Math.round((trioAllMP/trioAllMatches + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 + ' Minutes';
var trioAllWins = data.data.stats.all.trio.wins;
var trioAllWinrate = data.data.stats.all.trio.winRate;
var trioAllKills = data.data.stats.all.trio.kills;
var trioAllDeaths = data.data.stats.all.trio.deaths;
var trioAllKd = data.data.stats.all.trio.kd;
var trioAllKPM = data.data.stats.all.trio.killsPerMin;
var trioAllScore = data.data.stats.all.trio.score;
var trioAllSPM = data.data.stats.all.trio.scorePerMin;
var trioAllSPM2 = data.data.stats.all.trio.scorePerMatch;
var trioAllPlacetop3 = data.data.stats.all.trio.top3;
var trioAllPlacetop6 = data.data.stats.all.trio.top6;
var trioAllPO = data.data.stats.all.trio.playersOutlived;
var trioTime = time_convert(trioAllMP);
document.getElementById('trioAllMP').innerHTML = '<b>Time Played:</b> ' + trioTime;
document.getElementById('trioAllScore').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Score:</b> ' + trioAllScore;
document.getElementById('trioAllMatches').innerHTML = '<b>Number of Matches:</b> '+ trioAllMatches;
document.getElementById('trioMatchLength').innerHTML ='<b>AVG Length of Match:</b> '+ trioML;
document.getElementById('trioAllWins').innerHTML = '<b>Total Wins:</b> ' + trioAllWins;
document.getElementById('trioAllWinrate').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Winrate:</b> ' + trioAllWinrate;
document.getElementById('trioAllKills').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Eliminations:</b> ' + trioAllKills;
document.getElementById('trioAllDeaths').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Deaths:</b> ' + trioAllDeaths;
document.getElementById('trioAllKd').innerHTML = '<b>Trio K/D Rate:</b> ' + trioAllKd;
document.getElementById('trioAllKPM').innerHTML = '<b>Eliminations Per Minute:</b> ' + trioAllKPM;
document.getElementById('trioAllSPM').innerHTML ='<b>Trio Score Per  Minute:</b> ' + trioAllSPM;
document.getElementById('trioAllSPM2').innerHTML ='<b>Trio Score Per Match:</b> ' + trioAllSPM2;
document.getElementById('trioAllPlacetop3').innerHTML ='<b>Placed Top 3:</b> '+ trioAllPlacetop3;
document.getElementById('trioAllPlacetop6').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 6:</b> '+ trioAllPlacetop6;
document.getElementById('trioAllPO').innerHTML = '<b>Players Outlasted:</b> ' + trioAllPO;
}
if(typeof data.data.stats.all.trio == "null") {
  $(".trioStats").remove;
}
```

All code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <!--<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,8
    00;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Commissioner:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito:ital,wght@0,200;0,300;0,400;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Work+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Barlow:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;0,800;0,900;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700;1,800;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital,wght@0,100;0,200;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,600;0,700;1,100;1,200;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,600;1,700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Oxygen:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Hind+Siliguri:wght@300;400;500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,700;1,900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">-->
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Google+Sans+Display:wght@300;400;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css"
    />

    <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

    <!--
fonts:
font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Work Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Barlow', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Hind Siliguri', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;

-->
  </head>
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: BurbankBigCondensed-Black;
      src: url('Burbank Big Condensed Black.ttf') format('opentype');
      font-weight: 200;
    }
    body {
      line-height: 0.7em;
      font-family: 'Google Sans Display', sans-serif;
    }

    .box {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
    }
    .hide{
      display:none;
    }
  </style>
  <body>
    <form id="form" onsubmit="return false;">
      <input type="text" id="myText" value="chefbezos" />
      <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    </form>
    <h2 id="name"></h2>
    <h2 id="userId"></h2>
    <div class="col s3 overallStats">
      <h6 class="specialTag" id="overallAllMP"></h6>
      <h6 class="specialTag" id="overallAllWins"></h6>
      <h6 class="specialTag" id="overallAllMatches"></h6>
      <h6 class="specialTag" id="overallAllScore"></h6>
      <h6 class="specialTag" id="overallMatchLength"></h6>
      <h6 class="specialTag" id="overallAllWinrate"></h6>
      <h6 class="specialTag" id="overallAllKills"></h6>
      <h6 class="specialTag" id="overallAllDeaths"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllKd"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllKPM"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllSPM"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllSPM2"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllPlacetop3"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllPlacetop5"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllPlacetop6"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllPlacetop10"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllPlacetop12"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllPlacetop25"></h6>
      <h6 id="overallAllPO"></h6>
    </div>
    
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col s3 soloStats">
        <h2>Solo Stats</h2>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="soloAllMP"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="soloAllMatches"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="soloMatchLength"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="soloAllWins"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="soloAllWinrate"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="soloAllKills"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="soloAllDeaths"></h6>
        <h6 id="soloAllKd"></h6>
        <h6 id="soloAllKPM"></h6>
        <h6 id="soloAllScore"></h6>
        <h6 id="soloAllSPM"></h6>
        <h6 id="soloAllSPM2"></h6>
        <h6 id="soloAllPlacetop10"></h6>
        <h6 id="soloAllPlacetop25"></h6>
        <h6 id="soloAllPO"></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col s3 duoStats">
        <h2>Duo Stats</h2>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="duoAllMP"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="duoAllMatches"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="duoMatchLength"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="duoAllWins"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="duoAllWinrate"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="duoAllKills"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="duoAllDeaths"></h6>
        <h6 id="duoAllKd"></h6>
        <h6 id="duoAllKPM"></h6>
        <h6 id="duoAllScore"></h6>
        <h6 id="duoAllSPM"></h6>
        <h6 id="duoAllSPM2"></h6>
        <h6 id="duoAllPlacetop5"></h6>
        <h6 id="duoAllPlacetop12"></h6>
        <h6 id="duoAllPO"></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col s3 trioStats">
        <h2>Trio Stats</h2>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="trioAllMP"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="trioAllMatches"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="trioMatchLength"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="trioAllWins"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="trioAllWinrate"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="trioAllKills"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="trioAllDeaths"></h6>
        <h6 id="trioAllKd"></h6>
        <h6 id="trioAllKPM"></h6>
        <h6 id="trioAllScore"></h6>
        <h6 id="trioAllSPM"></h6>
        <h6 id="trioAllSPM2"></h6>
        <h6 id="trioAllPlacetop3"></h6>
        <h6 id="trioAllPlacetop6"></h6>
        <h6 id="trioAllPO"></h6>
      </div>
      <div class="col s3 squadStats">
        <h2>Squad Stats</h2>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="squadAllMP"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="squadAllMatches"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="squadMatchLength"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="squadAllWins"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="squadAllWinrate"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="squadAllKills"></h6>
        <h6 class="specialTag" id="squadAllDeaths"></h6>
        <h6 id="squadAllKd"></h6>
        <h6 id="squadAllKPM"></h6>
        <h6 id="squadAllScore"></h6>
        <h6 id="squadAllSPM"></h6>
        <h6 id="squadAllSPM2"></h6>
        <h6 id="squadAllPlacetop3"></h6>
        <h6 id="squadAllPlacetop6"></h6>
        <h6 id="squadAllPO"></h6>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function myFunction() {
        var username = document.getElementById('myText').value;
        $.getJSON({
          url: 'https://fortnite-api.com/v1/stats/br/v2?name=' + username + '',
          success: function (data) {
            if(typeof data.data.stats.all.trio == "null") {
              $(".trioStats").addClass("hide");

            }
            console.log( data.data.stats.all.trio);
             if(typeof data.data.stats.all.trio == "null") {
var trioAllMP = data.data.stats.all.trio.minutesPlayed;
var trioAllMatches = data.data.stats.all.trio.matches;
var trioML = Math.round((trioAllMP/trioAllMatches + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 + ' Minutes';
var trioAllWins = data.data.stats.all.trio.wins;
var trioAllWinrate = data.data.stats.all.trio.winRate;
var trioAllKills = data.data.stats.all.trio.kills;
var trioAllDeaths = data.data.stats.all.trio.deaths;
var trioAllKd = data.data.stats.all.trio.kd;
var trioAllKPM = data.data.stats.all.trio.killsPerMin;
var trioAllScore = data.data.stats.all.trio.score;
var trioAllSPM = data.data.stats.all.trio.scorePerMin;
var trioAllSPM2 = data.data.stats.all.trio.scorePerMatch;
var trioAllPlacetop3 = data.data.stats.all.trio.top3;
var trioAllPlacetop6 = data.data.stats.all.trio.top6;
var trioAllPO = data.data.stats.all.trio.playersOutlived;
var trioTime = time_convert(trioAllMP);
document.getElementById('trioAllMP').innerHTML = '<b>Time Played:</b> ' + trioTime;
document.getElementById('trioAllScore').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Score:</b> ' + trioAllScore;
document.getElementById('trioAllMatches').innerHTML = '<b>Number of Matches:</b> '+ trioAllMatches;
document.getElementById('trioMatchLength').innerHTML ='<b>AVG Length of Match:</b> '+ trioML;
document.getElementById('trioAllWins').innerHTML = '<b>Total Wins:</b> ' + trioAllWins;
document.getElementById('trioAllWinrate').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Winrate:</b> ' + trioAllWinrate;
document.getElementById('trioAllKills').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Eliminations:</b> ' + trioAllKills;
document.getElementById('trioAllDeaths').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Deaths:</b> ' + trioAllDeaths;
document.getElementById('trioAllKd').innerHTML = '<b>Trio K/D Rate:</b> ' + trioAllKd;
document.getElementById('trioAllKPM').innerHTML = '<b>Eliminations Per Minute:</b> ' + trioAllKPM;
document.getElementById('trioAllSPM').innerHTML ='<b>Trio Score Per  Minute:</b> ' + trioAllSPM;
document.getElementById('trioAllSPM2').innerHTML ='<b>Trio Score Per Match:</b> ' + trioAllSPM2;
document.getElementById('trioAllPlacetop3').innerHTML ='<b>Placed Top 3:</b> '+ trioAllPlacetop3;
document.getElementById('trioAllPlacetop6').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 6:</b> '+ trioAllPlacetop6;
document.getElementById('trioAllPO').innerHTML = '<b>Players Outlasted:</b> ' + trioAllPO;
}else if(typeof data.data.stats.all.trio == "null") {
  $(".trioStats").addClass("hide");
} 
            function time_convert(num) {
              var hours = Math.floor(num / 60);
              var minutes = num % 60;
              return hours + ' Hr ' + minutes + ' Min';
            }
            
var overallAllMP = data.data.stats.all.overall.minutesPlayed;
var overallAllMatches = data.data.stats.all.overall.matches;
var overallML = Math.round((overallAllMP/overallAllMatches + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 + ' Minutes';
var overallAllWins = data.data.stats.all.overall.wins;
var overallAllWinrate = data.data.stats.all.overall.winRate;
var overallAllKills = data.data.stats.all.overall.kills;
var overallAllDeaths = data.data.stats.all.overall.deaths;
var overallAllKd = data.data.stats.all.overall.kd;
var overallAllKPM = data.data.stats.all.overall.killsPerMin;
var overallAllScore = data.data.stats.all.overall.score;
var overallAllSPM = data.data.stats.all.overall.scorePerMin;
var overallAllSPM2 = data.data.stats.all.overall.scorePerMatch;
var overallAllPlacetop3 = data.data.stats.all.overall.top3;
var overallAllPlacetop5 = data.data.stats.all.overall.top5;
var overallAllPlacetop6 = data.data.stats.all.overall.top6;
var overallAllPlacetop10 = data.data.stats.all.overall.top10;
var overallAllPlacetop12 = data.data.stats.all.overall.top12;
var overallAllPlacetop25 = data.data.stats.all.overall.top25;
var overallAllPO = data.data.stats.all.overall.playersOutlived;
var overallTime = time_convert(overallAllMP);
document.getElementById('overallAllMP').innerHTML = '<b>Time Played:</b> ' + overallTime;
document.getElementById('overallAllScore').innerHTML = '<b>Overall Score:</b> ' + overallAllScore;
document.getElementById('overallAllMatches').innerHTML = '<b>Number of Matches:</b> '+ overallAllMatches;
document.getElementById('overallMatchLength').innerHTML ='<b>AVG Length of Match:</b> '+ overallML;
document.getElementById('overallAllWins').innerHTML = '<b>Total Wins:</b> ' + overallAllWins;
document.getElementById('overallAllWinrate').innerHTML = '<b>Overall Winrate:</b> ' + overallAllWinrate + '%';
document.getElementById('overallAllKills').innerHTML = '<b>Overall Eliminations:</b> ' + overallAllKills;
document.getElementById('overallAllDeaths').innerHTML = '<b>Overall Deaths:</b> ' + overallAllDeaths;
document.getElementById('overallAllKd').innerHTML = '<b>Overall K/D Rate:</b> ' + overallAllKd;
document.getElementById('overallAllKPM').innerHTML = '<b>Eliminations Per Minute:</b> ' + overallAllKPM;
document.getElementById('overallAllSPM').innerHTML ='<b>Overall Score Per  Minute:</b> ' + overallAllSPM;
document.getElementById('overallAllSPM2').innerHTML ='<b>Overall Score Per Match:</b> ' + overallAllSPM2;
document.getElementById('overallAllPlacetop3').innerHTML = '<b>Placed Top 3:</b> ' + overallAllPlacetop3;
document.getElementById('overallAllPlacetop5').innerHTML = '<b>Placed top 5:</b> ' + overallAllPlacetop5;
document.getElementById('overallAllPlacetop6').innerHTML = '<b>Placed top 6:</b> ' + overallAllPlacetop6;
document.getElementById('overallAllPlacetop10').innerHTML ='<b>Placed Top 10:</b> '+ overallAllPlacetop5;
document.getElementById('overallAllPlacetop12').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 12:</b> '+ overallAllPlacetop12;
document.getElementById('overallAllPlacetop25').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 25:</b> '+ overallAllPlacetop25;
document.getElementById('overallAllPO').innerHTML = '<b>Players Outlasted:</b> ' + overallAllPO;


var duoAllMP = data.data.stats.all.duo.minutesPlayed;
var duoAllMatches = data.data.stats.all.duo.matches;
var duoML = Math.round((duoAllMP/duoAllMatches + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 + ' Minutes';
var duoAllWins = data.data.stats.all.duo.wins;
var duoAllWinrate = data.data.stats.all.duo.winRate;
var duoAllKills = data.data.stats.all.duo.kills;
var duoAllDeaths = data.data.stats.all.duo.deaths;
var duoAllKd = data.data.stats.all.duo.kd;
var duoAllKPM = data.data.stats.all.duo.killsPerMin;
var duoAllScore = data.data.stats.all.duo.score;
var duoAllSPM = data.data.stats.all.duo.scorePerMin;
var duoAllSPM2 = data.data.stats.all.duo.scorePerMatch;
var duoAllPlacetop5 = data.data.stats.all.duo.top5;
var duoAllPlacetop12 = data.data.stats.all.duo.top12;
var duoAllPO = data.data.stats.all.duo.playersOutlived;
var duoTime = time_convert(duoAllMP);
document.getElementById('duoAllMP').innerHTML = '<b>Time Played:</b> ' + duoTime;
document.getElementById('duoAllScore').innerHTML = '<b>duo Score:</b> ' + duoAllScore;
document.getElementById('duoAllMatches').innerHTML = '<b>Number of Matches:</b> '+ duoAllMatches;
document.getElementById('duoMatchLength').innerHTML ='<b>AVG Length of Match:</b> '+ duoML;
document.getElementById('duoAllWins').innerHTML = '<b>Total Wins:</b> ' + duoAllWins;
document.getElementById('duoAllWinrate').innerHTML = '<b>Duo Winrate:</b> ' + duoAllWinrate + '%';
document.getElementById('duoAllKills').innerHTML = '<b>Duo Eliminations:</b> ' + duoAllKills;
document.getElementById('duoAllDeaths').innerHTML = '<b>Duo Deaths:</b> ' + duoAllDeaths;
document.getElementById('duoAllKd').innerHTML = '<b>Duo K/D Rate:</b> ' + duoAllKd;
document.getElementById('duoAllKPM').innerHTML = '<b>Eliminations Per Minute:</b> ' + duoAllKPM;
document.getElementById('duoAllSPM').innerHTML ='<b>Duo Score Per  Minute:</b> ' + duoAllSPM;
document.getElementById('duoAllSPM2').innerHTML ='<b>Duo Score Per Match:</b> ' + duoAllSPM2;
document.getElementById('duoAllPlacetop5').innerHTML = '<b>Placed top 5:</b> ' + duoAllPlacetop5;
document.getElementById('duoAllPlacetop12').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 12:</b> '+ duoAllPlacetop12;
document.getElementById('duoAllPO').innerHTML = '<b>Players Outlasted:</b> ' + duoAllPO;


var soloAllMP = data.data.stats.all.solo.minutesPlayed;
var soloAllMatches = data.data.stats.all.solo.matches;
var soloML = Math.round((soloAllMP/soloAllMatches + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 + ' Minutes';
var soloAllWins = data.data.stats.all.solo.wins;
var soloAllWinrate = data.data.stats.all.solo.winRate;
var soloAllKills = data.data.stats.all.solo.kills;
var soloAllDeaths = data.data.stats.all.solo.deaths;
var soloAllKd = data.data.stats.all.solo.kd;
var soloAllKPM = data.data.stats.all.solo.killsPerMin;
var soloAllScore = data.data.stats.all.solo.score;
var soloAllSPM = data.data.stats.all.solo.scorePerMin;
var soloAllSPM2 = data.data.stats.all.solo.scorePerMatch;
var soloAllPlacetop10 = data.data.stats.all.solo.top10;
var soloAllPlacetop25 = data.data.stats.all.solo.top25;
var soloAllPO = data.data.stats.all.solo.playersOutlived;
var soloTime = time_convert(soloAllMP);
document.getElementById('soloAllMP').innerHTML = '<b>Time Played:</b> ' + soloTime;
document.getElementById('soloAllScore').innerHTML = '<b>solo Score:</b> ' + soloAllScore;
document.getElementById('soloAllMatches').innerHTML = '<b>Number of Matches:</b> '+ soloAllMatches;
document.getElementById('soloMatchLength').innerHTML ='<b>AVG Length of Match:</b> '+ soloML;
document.getElementById('soloAllWins').innerHTML = '<b>Total Wins:</b> ' + soloAllWins;
document.getElementById('soloAllWinrate').innerHTML = '<b>Solo Winrate:</b> ' + soloAllWinrate + '%';
document.getElementById('soloAllKills').innerHTML = '<b>Solo Eliminations:</b> ' + soloAllKills;
document.getElementById('soloAllDeaths').innerHTML = '<b>Solo Deaths:</b> ' + soloAllDeaths;
document.getElementById('soloAllKd').innerHTML = '<b>Solo K/D Rate:</b> ' + soloAllKd;
document.getElementById('soloAllKPM').innerHTML = '<b>Eliminations Per Minute:</b> ' + soloAllKPM;
document.getElementById('soloAllSPM').innerHTML ='<b>Solo Score Per  Minute:</b> ' + soloAllSPM;
document.getElementById('soloAllSPM2').innerHTML ='<b>Solo Score Per Match:</b> ' + soloAllSPM2;
document.getElementById('soloAllPlacetop10').innerHTML ='<b>Placed Top 10:</b> '+ soloAllPlacetop10;
document.getElementById('soloAllPlacetop25').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 25:</b> '+ soloAllPlacetop25;
document.getElementById('soloAllPO').innerHTML = '<b>Players Outlasted:</b> ' + soloAllPO;


var squadAllMP = data.data.stats.all.squad.minutesPlayed;
var squadAllMatches = data.data.stats.all.squad.matches;
var squadML = Math.round((squadAllMP/squadAllMatches + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 + ' Minutes';
var squadAllWins = data.data.stats.all.squad.wins;
var squadAllWinrate = data.data.stats.all.squad.winRate;
var squadAllKills = data.data.stats.all.squad.kills;
var squadAllDeaths = data.data.stats.all.squad.deaths;
var squadAllKd = data.data.stats.all.squad.kd;
var squadAllKPM = data.data.stats.all.squad.killsPerMin;
var squadAllScore = data.data.stats.all.squad.score;
var squadAllSPM = data.data.stats.all.squad.scorePerMin;
var squadAllSPM2 = data.data.stats.all.squad.scorePerMatch;
var squadAllPlacetop3 = data.data.stats.all.squad.top3;
var squadAllPlacetop6 = data.data.stats.all.squad.top6;
var squadAllPO = data.data.stats.all.squad.playersOutlived;
var squadTime = time_convert(squadAllMP);
document.getElementById('squadAllMP').innerHTML = '<b>Time Played:</b> ' + squadTime;
document.getElementById('squadAllScore').innerHTML = '<b>Squad Score:</b> ' + squadAllScore;
document.getElementById('squadAllMatches').innerHTML = '<b>Number of Matches:</b> '+ squadAllMatches;
document.getElementById('squadMatchLength').innerHTML ='<b>AVG Length of Match:</b> '+ squadML;
document.getElementById('squadAllWins').innerHTML = '<b>Total Wins:</b> ' + squadAllWins;
document.getElementById('squadAllWinrate').innerHTML = '<b>Squad Winrate:</b> ' + squadAllWinrate + '%';
document.getElementById('squadAllKills').innerHTML = '<b>Squad Eliminations:</b> ' + squadAllKills;
document.getElementById('squadAllDeaths').innerHTML = '<b>Squad Deaths:</b> ' + squadAllDeaths;
document.getElementById('squadAllKd').innerHTML = '<b>squad K/D Rate:</b> ' + squadAllKd;
document.getElementById('squadAllKPM').innerHTML = '<b>Eliminations Per Minute:</b> ' + squadAllKPM;
document.getElementById('squadAllSPM').innerHTML ='<b>Squad Score Per  Minute:</b> ' + squadAllSPM;
document.getElementById('squadAllSPM2').innerHTML ='<b>Squad Score Per Match:</b> ' + squadAllSPM2;
document.getElementById('squadAllPlacetop3').innerHTML ='<b>Placed Top 3:</b> '+ squadAllPlacetop3;
document.getElementById('squadAllPlacetop6').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 6:</b> '+ squadAllPlacetop6;
document.getElementById('squadAllPO').innerHTML = '<b>Players Outlasted:</b> ' + squadAllPO;
          },
        });
        $.getJSON({
          url: ' https://fortniteapi.io/v1/stats?account=f313b75dc8864c35829c844e1637be4d',

          headers: { Authorization: '5d661c2a-59e41e68-854c5a46-6f742ef8' },
          success: function (data) {
            console.log(data)
          }
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: null (actual null value) and the string “null” aren’t the same thing.

Comment: hmm, then how do I tell JS that I want the real null?

Comment: Don’t use a string? Check for null (a null), not “null” (a string)

Comment: doesn't work, even without string

Comment: But your logic seems backwards; you basically say “if this is null then access some properties from it. But it’s null, it won’t have any.

Comment: “Doesn’t work” is an insufficient description.

Comment: The div is still visible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use indentation...

```
if(data.data.stats.all.trio == null) {
var trioAllMP = data.data.stats.all.trio.minutesPlayed;
var trioAllMatches = data.data.stats.all.trio.matches;
var trioML = Math.round((trioAllMP/trioAllMatches + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 + ' Minutes';
var trioAllWins = data.data.stats.all.trio.wins;
var trioAllWinrate = data.data.stats.all.trio.winRate;
var trioAllKills = data.data.stats.all.trio.kills;
var trioAllDeaths = data.data.stats.all.trio.deaths;
var trioAllKd = data.data.stats.all.trio.kd;
var trioAllKPM = data.data.stats.all.trio.killsPerMin;
var trioAllScore = data.data.stats.all.trio.score;
var trioAllSPM = data.data.stats.all.trio.scorePerMin;
var trioAllSPM2 = data.data.stats.all.trio.scorePerMatch;
var trioAllPlacetop3 = data.data.stats.all.trio.top3;
var trioAllPlacetop6 = data.data.stats.all.trio.top6;
var trioAllPO = data.data.stats.all.trio.playersOutlived;
var trioTime = time_convert(trioAllMP);
document.getElementById('trioAllMP').innerHTML = '<b>Time Played:</b> ' + trioTime;
document.getElementById('trioAllScore').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Score:</b> ' + trioAllScore;
document.getElementById('trioAllMatches').innerHTML = '<b>Number of Matches:</b> '+ trioAllMatches;
document.getElementById('trioMatchLength').innerHTML ='<b>AVG Length of Match:</b> '+ trioML;
document.getElementById('trioAllWins').innerHTML = '<b>Total Wins:</b> ' + trioAllWins;
document.getElementById('trioAllWinrate').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Winrate:</b> ' + trioAllWinrate;
document.getElementById('trioAllKills').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Eliminations:</b> ' + trioAllKills;
document.getElementById('trioAllDeaths').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Deaths:</b> ' + trioAllDeaths;
document.getElementById('trioAllKd').innerHTML = '<b>Trio K/D Rate:</b> ' + trioAllKd;
document.getElementById('trioAllKPM').innerHTML = '<b>Eliminations Per Minute:</b> ' + trioAllKPM;
document.getElementById('trioAllSPM').innerHTML ='<b>Trio Score Per  Minute:</b> ' + trioAllSPM;
document.getElementById('trioAllSPM2').innerHTML ='<b>Trio Score Per Match:</b> ' + trioAllSPM2;
document.getElementById('trioAllPlacetop3').innerHTML ='<b>Placed Top 3:</b> '+ trioAllPlacetop3;
document.getElementById('trioAllPlacetop6').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 6:</b> '+ trioAllPlacetop6;
document.getElementById('trioAllPO').innerHTML = '<b>Players Outlasted:</b> ' + trioAllPO;
```

}

consider using only one if statement if the comparison is the same and they are next to each other!

```
if(data.data.stats.all.trio == null) {
var trioAllMP = data.data.stats.all.trio.minutesPlayed;
var trioAllMatches = data.data.stats.all.trio.matches;
var trioML = Math.round((trioAllMP/trioAllMatches + Number.EPSILON) * 100) / 100 + ' Minutes';
var trioAllWins = data.data.stats.all.trio.wins;
var trioAllWinrate = data.data.stats.all.trio.winRate;
var trioAllKills = data.data.stats.all.trio.kills;
var trioAllDeaths = data.data.stats.all.trio.deaths;
var trioAllKd = data.data.stats.all.trio.kd;
var trioAllKPM = data.data.stats.all.trio.killsPerMin;
var trioAllScore = data.data.stats.all.trio.score;
var trioAllSPM = data.data.stats.all.trio.scorePerMin;
var trioAllSPM2 = data.data.stats.all.trio.scorePerMatch;
var trioAllPlacetop3 = data.data.stats.all.trio.top3;
var trioAllPlacetop6 = data.data.stats.all.trio.top6;
var trioAllPO = data.data.stats.all.trio.playersOutlived;
var trioTime = time_convert(trioAllMP);
document.getElementById('trioAllMP').innerHTML = '<b>Time Played:</b> ' + trioTime;
document.getElementById('trioAllScore').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Score:</b> ' + trioAllScore;
document.getElementById('trioAllMatches').innerHTML = '<b>Number of Matches:</b> '+ trioAllMatches;
document.getElementById('trioMatchLength').innerHTML ='<b>AVG Length of Match:</b> '+ trioML;
document.getElementById('trioAllWins').innerHTML = '<b>Total Wins:</b> ' + trioAllWins;
document.getElementById('trioAllWinrate').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Winrate:</b> ' + trioAllWinrate;
document.getElementById('trioAllKills').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Eliminations:</b> ' + trioAllKills;
document.getElementById('trioAllDeaths').innerHTML = '<b>Trio Deaths:</b> ' + trioAllDeaths;
document.getElementById('trioAllKd').innerHTML = '<b>Trio K/D Rate:</b> ' + trioAllKd;
document.getElementById('trioAllKPM').innerHTML = '<b>Eliminations Per Minute:</b> ' + trioAllKPM;
document.getElementById('trioAllSPM').innerHTML ='<b>Trio Score Per  Minute:</b> ' + trioAllSPM;
document.getElementById('trioAllSPM2').innerHTML ='<b>Trio Score Per Match:</b> ' + trioAllSPM2;
document.getElementById('trioAllPlacetop3').innerHTML ='<b>Placed Top 3:</b> '+ trioAllPlacetop3;
document.getElementById('trioAllPlacetop6').innerHTML='<b>Placed top 6:</b> '+ trioAllPlacetop6;
document.getElementById('trioAllPO').innerHTML = '<b>Players Outlasted:</b> ' + trioAllPO;

$(".trioStats").remove;
}
```

and more importantly:
i suggest you install JSON Formater extension for you browser, then you will see more clearly that the data you are trying to access is not there!
and remove the "typeof", because it's not necessary to locate the `null`

Comment: so i see the indentation is a bug from here, not you :|

Comment: i suggest you install JSON Formater extension for you browser, then you will see more clearly that the data you are trying to access is not there!

Comment: wdym? data.data.stats.all.trio exists

Comment: I know it is not there, I want it to detect that it doesn't exist.  https://fortnite-api.com/v1/stats/br/v2?name=chefbezos is an example endpoint, change it to

Comment: and then you have data in there. A user input will control the name parameter

Comment: on the name "ninja" you have data inside "data.stats.all.trio"... but on name "chefbezos", that data is null, once you do == null, if will enter the if statement and try to populate the "trioAllMP" var with the contents of "trio.minutesPlayed", but for it to enter, it means trio is null (empty), so minutesPlayed doesn't exist!

Your code has a logical flaw...

Comment: i think you are trying to see if it is != null, so it exists......

Comment: without the "typeof" btw

Comment: Thank! Removing the typeof was the issue. Update your answer and I will accpept